# ArgoCD Image Updater Error: 'certificate signed by unknown authority' with Docker Registry

Tags: argocd

I'm trying to set up a simple image updating process using ArgoCD Image Updater, but I've run into the following issue.

```bash
time="2023-12-16T10:10:27Z" level=error msg="Could not get tags from registry: Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" alias=img application=argo-image-updater2-app image_name=ghalamif/imageupdater image_tag=v0.1.0 registry=
time="2023-12-16T10:10:27Z" level=info msg="Processing results: applications=1 images_considered=1 images_skipped=0 images_updated=0 errors=1"
```

by the way, my DockerHub repo is public.
here is my applicatio.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: argo-image-updater2-app
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers: 
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
  annotations:
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/image-list: img=ghalamif/imageupdater:~v0.1
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/write-back-method: git 
    argocd-image-updater.argoproj.io/git-branch: main
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/ghalamif/prfaps.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: argo-image-updater/image-updater
    helm: 
      valueFiles:
        - values.yaml
  destination: 
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: argo-image-updater2-app

  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true

    automated:
      selfHeal: true
      prune: true
```

Has anyone experienced this before, or does anyone have any insights on how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and updating the ArgoCD Image Updater docker image to 0.12.2 fixed the issue.

The "root cause" is that, I installed the image updater using the official documentation https://argocd-image-updater.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/installation/#apply-the-installation-manifests which is using a git tag `stable` which turns out is using old version of the image updater docker image, *0.12.0*, which is ~2y old ([ref](https://quay.io/repository/argoprojlabs/argocd-image-updater?tab=tags))

You can install 0.12.2 by running:

```
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj-labs/argocd-image-updater/v0.12.2/manifests/install.yaml
```

Note: there is a new `latest` version which I haven't tried.

Comment: Bless you, this issue was driving me nuts. This is the correct answer, thanks a lot!